# R - How to change the value of an input tag using RSelenium?

Tags: html, r, rselenium

I want to change the page size on a web site as shown in the image using RSelenium. [Page Size image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Cde.jpg)

Its actually a combobox with the following html written for it:

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="ctl00$ContentBody$rgridPDPList$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$PageSizeComboBox" class="rcbInput" id="ctl00_ContentBody_rgridPDPList_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Input" value="10" readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

Here the value is 10 and the other options for the drop box are 20, 50.

I tried using the below lines of code:

```
opt <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/input[@value = '20']")
opt$clickElement()
```

But i am getting error as:

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
Also i used this:

```
xpathSApply(elemxml,"//input[@value]",xmlGetAttr,"value")
```

This is giving me the value as 10, but I am not able to set some other value using this.
I tried using findElements also, but no luck.

Can you please let me know how to change this value to 20 or 50 using RSelenium (or any other method if possible).
Also is it possible to mention a value that is not from the combo box for eg: 1500.

I am sorry I cannot share the link as it is protected.
Kindly let me know if any other inputs are required from my side.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution. findElement and clickElement did the job.